# Catching JSON response form web post request in android

Tags: android, json, api, post, response

I have been working with **WebView** in android for loading HTML files in android. On my way, I am trying to test an API service that will let me access the services if I provide required parameter and responds in JSON. 
**My question is, How can I parse the obtained JSON from the FORM POST request in android and reuse the resultants.**

My HTML for form with post method is provided below:

```
     <form method="post" action="htts://www.ipay.com.np/api/v2/recharge">
    <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Username:</label>
      <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="choose">Amount:</label>
    <select name="mid"  class="form-control" id="mid" placeholder="Query">
      <option value="null">what-would-you-like-to-do</option>
      <option value="37">NTC-POSTPAID RECHARGE</option>
      <option value="35">NTC LANDLINE PSTN</option>
      <option value="20">NCELL AIRTIME</option>
      <option value="36">NTC PREPAID</option>
      <option value="33">ADSL UNLIMITED</option>
      <option value="39">ADSL VOLUME</option>
      <option value="46">UTL TOPUP</option>

  </select>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" min="1" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
      <select name="amount"  class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        <option value="null">select-amount</option>
        <option value="Rs.10">10</option>
        <option value="Rs.20">20</option>
        <option value="Rs.30">30</option>
        <option value="Rs.40">40</option>
        <option value="Rs.50">50</option>
        <option value="Rs.100">100</option>
        <option value="Rs.100+">100+</option>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And the responce example i get from the following POST method is:

```
    {

"txn_no" : 12343,

"ord_no" : 1222,

"status" : "paid",

"merchant" : "Ncell Air time",

"description" : "recharge of...",

"amount" : 20.00, "reward" : 0.02

}
```

It would be very helpfull, if i only get idea to catch the json response in my android application.

Comment: You can create an activity with appropriate UI for input fields and send a post request from there, Why are you using a WebView for achieving it ?

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani I don't have appropriate URL, I need to use it from a website.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use webview for its, you can achieve its by HttpPost in activity,

```
public boolean validateLogin()
            {
                try {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //call webservice and get json response
                    String JSONStr = PostData();
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONStr);
                    String status = jsonObject.get("success").toString();
                    return status.equals("1");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
             public String PostData() {
                    String jsonResponse = "";
                    String URL = "https://example.com/Login.php?Email=" + str_email + "&Password=" + str_password;
                    try {
                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                        jsonResponse = readResponse(httpResponse);
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                    }
                    return jsonResponse;
                }

                public String readResponse(HttpResponse res) {
                    InputStream is = null;
                    String return_text = "";
                    try {
                        is = res.getEntity().getContent();
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                        String line = "";
                        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                        }
                        return_text = sb.toString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    return return_text;

                }
```

Comment: I just have the base URL. The thing is,
`https://example.com/Login.php?Email=" + str_email + "&Password=" + str_password` 

how do I figure out that the value is to be sent in Email field or something else?  
Are they the one found inside name attribute in the POST request from the html form POST?
I am confused

Comment: "Email" is one field in my Query String which is get by my php web service.  In web service i have file named Login.php in which i retrieve email field. $email=$_REQUEST["Email"];